# Word interop apply style to all the matches

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-automation, word-interop

I have written code to find citations in the word file and trying to make all the citations superscript.

```
Word.Range rngCitations = doc.Content;
        rngCitations.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
        rngCitations.Find.Text = @"(\[[0-9]{1,}[,0-9]*\])";
        if (rngCitations.Find.Execute())
        {
            rngCitations.Font.Superscript = 1;
            rngCitations.Font.Bold = 1;

         }
```

But, only first match updating to Superscript. How do I change this code to apply styling to all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop you can use the official example: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-loop-through-found-items-in-documents?view=vs-2019

```
rng.Find.ClearFormatting(); 
rng.Find.Forward = true; 
rng.Find.Text = "find me"; 

rng.Find.Execute(
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

while (rng.Find.Found) 
{ 
    intFound++;
    rng.Find.Execute(
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

In your case change if with while

```
while (rngCitations.Find.Execute())
{
      rngCitations.Font.Superscript = 1;
      rngCitations.Font.Bold = 1;
}
```